# What is the best way to read in four data files and place them into an array of structs using functions?

Tags: c++, arrays, input, struct

First, I am required to read in data from four input files. Second, I am required to create an array of structs and store the data into the structs. Thirdly, I must perform some manipulation on the data. Lastly, I am to print the manipulated data to an output file.

The first, I have never read in data from more than one file at a time. The second, I have never used a struct before, let alone an array of structs. I am stuck on the most effective method to read in the data from all four files and store that data into the array of structs.

Hence, my question to you is, what would be the best method for reading in the data?

I have been contemplating four different methods for a couple of hours now. Each one involves a while-loop with a “not end-of-file” Boolean expression.

Comment: Do you know how to read data from 1 input file? It is no different when reading from multiple files, simply open multiple file objects. What is hard about that? Have you ever worked with classes before? In C++, a struct is effectively the same as a class, the ONLY real difference is that struct members are `public` by default whereas class members are `private` by default. You say you have already considered multiple approaches to handling this task, so please update your question to show what you have already attempted that is not working for you. You are right that this is very basic stuff.

Comment: Don't worry too much about "most effective". Start with "effective" and go from there. You said you have ideas for how to proceed. Pick one, see how far you can take it, then come back here when you have a specific question and code showing what you have done so far.

Comment: Thanks! I will try these approaches and see what unfolds.

Comment: Does anyone know how to pass an array of structs?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  char text[200]; // store data in an array 

  fstream file;
  file.open ("example.txt", ios::out | ios::in ); // file name is exam for reading 



  // Reding from file
  file >> text;
  cout << text << endl; // print data of file thought array 

  //closing the file
  file.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Hope this will help you.